# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON with StorybookJS on React Native

Tags: react-native, storybook

This happens whenever I navigate to a new Story within the Storybook Navigator. Thanks!

```
ExceptionsManager.js:126 Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HooksContext'
    |     property 'currentContext' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'hooks' closes the circle
```

I'm using `React Native` `0.61.5` and `@storybook/react-native` `5.3.9`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same issue and unfortunately don't have enough experience with Storybook or React Native to diagnose.

However, I was able to patch the module as described in https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9294, i.e. "hooks.currentContext = Object.assign({}, context, { hooks: null });"

To reiterate, this is not a perfect solution, as the original bug comes from the nested, circular relationship between currentContext and hooks. This simply sets hooks to null to terminate the circular structure.

Comment: If anyone wants to jump straight to the comment on that issue that fixes the issue. Here is the link: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9294#issuecomment-580582681

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting `onDeviceUI` to false solves this issue when I use storybook web UI.

storybook/index

```js
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
  asyncStorage: require('@react-native-community/async-storage').AsyncStorage,
  onDeviceUI: false,
  shouldPersistSelection: true,
  shouldDisableKeyboardAvoidingView: true,
  // isUIHidden: true,
})
```